# Can we shrink a 1.6 TB SQL Server DB in Simple mode with only 12 GB Storage left?

Tags: sql-server, storage

We saw your article about this topic and wondered if you can answer this question:
Can we shrink a 1.6 TB SQL Server DB in Simple mode with only 12 GB Storage left?

Here is your article that we saw:

> If you're looking for a GUI way to do it, set your DB to SIMPLE
>   RECOVERY (right-click on DB in SSMS, go to properties, Options,
>   Recovery Model -> Simple).  Then do the shrink of files - firstly your
>   log file and then your data file. To do so, right-click on DB in SSMS,
>   Tasks, Shrink, Files. Set FileType to log and and choose "Reorganise
>   pages..." and set as low as you can go. Repeat but set FileType to
>   Data. Set your DB back to FULL RECOVERY if it was on there before you
>   changed to SIMPLE RECOVERY above. If it was already set for SIMPLE
>   RECOVERY then just leave as is. This sort of shrinking creates a lot
>   of index fragmentation and probably shouldn't be a routine thing, but
>   it can get you out of a jam :) shareimprove this answer  answered Dec
>   3 '12 at 12:37

Ian Yates

Answer (score 0):

Referencing one of the answers in [how can i shrink the db in chunks?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3106389a-e6bc-41c8-b536-52a34d11d684/how-can-i-shrink-the-db530gb-in-chunks?forum=sqldatabaseengine)

[Sean Gallardy](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/41723/sean-gallardy-microsoft) offers this:

---

> You could achieve what you're looking for by creating a loop and
>   slowly decrementing the size of the files(s)/database in small amounts
>   and calling the shrink in succession.
>
> Pseudo code would be something such as:
>
> while the size is greater than my target
>
> 1. calculate the current size
> 2. set the desired size 100 MB less than the current
> 3. call shrink with the 100 MB less desired size
> 4. depending on server usage, a wait event could be put here (WAITFOR)

---

You might need to adjust your shrink numbers accordingly and naturally, this process will probably take a long time.